# Unable to make EventListener trigger only once JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a link which fires only once so that I can then change it to another EventListener.
When I press "Show More" I want the current EventListener to be removed since now it just continues triggering other "Show More-"links because of the solution I'm using with arrays.

This is the function I'm curruently using but I don't feel like it triggers the removeEventListener since I can press it multiple times. You can see this in my CodePen

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.showMoreLinks.length; i++)
{
    this.showMoreLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function handler(e) { 
        this.UpdateShowMore(i);
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Full Code:

https://codepen.io/indiehjaerta/pen/qoMLQK

Maybe this isn't even the smartest option so any other code advice is also appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your bound function is actually the same as your definition of `handler`, it returns a new function that has been bound to `this`, so `handler`s definition is unchanged and therefor not found when trying to remove. I'd suggest an arrow function to avoid using binding at. all:

```
let handler = e => {
    this.UpdateShowMore(i);
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
}
this.showMoreLinks[i].addEventListener( "click", handler );
```

This is of course the same as binding before and storing the result of the bind into the variable:

```
let handler = function( e ){
    this.UpdateShowMore(i);
    e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, handler);
}.bind( this );
this.showMoreLinks[i].addEventListener( "click", handler );
```

From MDN:

> The bind() method creates a **new function** that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

So after defining handler as `function handler(){}`, using bind will return a different *anonymous* function than `handler` with preset arguments that then gets used as event listener. You want to unlisten this returned function, not the original one, so you need to store the result of your bind in a variable for later use.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Works great now.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this is to set a flag on the event that makes the listner a on-time listner.

Please update your JavaScript code as:

```
this.showMoreLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function handler(e) { 
    this.UpdateShowMore(i);     
}.bind(this), {once : true});
```

You don't have to write any removeEventListner().

Comment: Its been forever since I read the docs on this and am now happy you prompted me to do so, this is very useful.